# What is the word for someone who doesn't appreciate their culture/heritage?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, pejorative-language

I met a person the other day who was overly critical about her culture/heritage when she described it. Is there a word to describe such a person or behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior can be the result of ***cultural cringe*** or ***cultural alienation***.

> Cultural cringe, in cultural studies and social anthropology, is an internalized inferiority complex that causes people in a country to **dismiss their own culture** as inferior to the cultures of other countries. It can also be manifested in individuals in the form of cultural alienation.
>
> The cultural cringe is tightly connected with "cultural alienation", that is, **the process of devaluing or abandoning one's own culture or cultural background**. A person who is culturally alienated places little value on their own or host culture, and instead hungers for that of a – sometimes imposed – colonising nation.
>
> <sup>http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cultural_cringe</sup>

Explanation from [TvTropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CulturalCringe):

> A person with a cultural cringe will tend to discount a lot of their own culture, and embrace another country's 'better' culture instead. In fact, it's common for people suffering from Cultural Cringe to disavow that there is a national culture at all.
>
> This isn't necessarily the opposite of Patriotic Fervor, nor is it necessarily the same thing as Boomerang Bigot. Someone with the Cringe may love his/her country and national heritage despite its supposed inferiority. As one may put it, their own culture may suck, but it's still their culture.
>
> Compare Internalized Categorism, where the character starts hating themselves for being a part of a culture perceived by others as "bad", rather then merely seeing their culture as inferior to other cultures.

Answer (score 2):

While the term *self-hating*, standing alone, is ususally applied to a person who dislikes themselves (see, e.g., *[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/self-hating)*) when combined with an ethnic reference, it is sometimes used to indicate a rejection of the group by an individual who generally would be considered a part of that group.

For example, the slang and pejorative term *[self-hating curry](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=self-hating%20curry)* is defined as

> An Indian person who is dissatisfied with their ancestry. [*Urban Dictionary*]

That entry also references the term *self-hating Jew*, which is discussed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-hating_Jew). [*Wikipedia*]

Answer (score 1):

I think there is more than one possible reason why someone may discount their national heritage. ermanen gives one possible answer: cultural cringe, a basic dislike of one's native culture.

Another reason may be **cosmopolitanism**. Someone with this world view is more interested in commonalities than differences between people, seeing humanity as one big world community. A person with this point of view may dislike the very idea of national heritage as a way of identifying people.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmopolitanism

For a cosmopolitan, national heritage is less important than other sources of cultural identity, such as their professional community, political views or some other subculture that the individual strongly identifies with.

Answer (score 0):

I've used 'cultural bastard' to describe a person that is of a culture by blood but doesn't identify with them.

"accident of birth" is used here -

> Why is it that every India-origin person to win a Nobel after
>   independence in the sciences is not an Indian citizen any more?
>   Hargobind Khurana won the prize for medicine in 1968, Subrahmanyan
>   Chandrasekhar for physics in 1983 and Venkatraman Ramakrishnan for
>   chemistry in 2009. All of them flowered only because they left India,
>   and not because they were Indians per se. They left India behind. In
>   fact, Ramakrishnan was downright rude when Indians called to
>   congratulate him in 2009. He said: “We are all human beings, and our
>   nationality is simply an accident of birth.”
>
> http://www.firstpost.com/india/nadella-as-microsoft-ceo-a-slap-in-the-face-for-indian-system-1374951.html

Comment: Is "cultural bastard" as negative as it sounds to me? Not caring about your heritage/culture is not per se a negative thing.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like she's at the 'reverse polarization' stage of her march toward adaptation in/to a new/changing culture and that she has simply not yet resolved her 'cultural disengagement' issues, but please give her time.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question, it's merely a personal comment.

Comment: Granted, the two possibilities offered in my answer (‘reverse [cultural] polarization’ and ‘cultural disengagement’) are phrases and not a single word as the questioner sought, but mine was not the only answer to offer alternative phrases instead of one single word in response to the question.  Regardless, I promise to read/interpret the questions more carefully/literally next time and, perhaps more importantly, to preface my answers with “My answer is:” to facilitate their comprehensibility while being read. 
cc: @ErikKowal

Comment: I think your terms describe the situation, but not the person, which is why others feel it does not answer the question.

Answer (score -5):

> [**philistine**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/philistine) *- a person who is hostile or indifferent to culture and the arts*

Comment: Voted this down because being against one's one home culture does not make that person against culture per se.

Comment: @Marky Mark: Fair comment, I suppose. The question doesn't specify whether the target appreciates *other* cultures. But if so, things get messy - we're skirting semantic territory more properly covered by words like *treason, traitors, treachery*. But taking your point, I've closevoted as "Unclear".