# What prefix might be adopted to designate own-race?

Tags: prefixes

Russo- is a synonym indicating pertaining to Russia.  Anglo- indicates pertaining to England.  Is there, or can one create or recommend a prefix which generalises to specifically means one's own race or country?

For example, somebody may wish to argue, rightly or wrongly, that some country (say UK for example) is more institutionally Anglophobic than Russia is Russophobic.  What [prefix]-phobic could cover the general case of pertaining to discriminating against one's own race or nation?

The best I have come up with is Indigenophobic.

Comment: Oikophobia (Greek: oîkos, 'house, household' + phóbos, 'fear'; related to domatophobia and ecophobia) is an aversion to a home environment, or an abnormal fear (phobia) of one's home and also a tendency to criticize or reject one's own culture and praise other cultures. (Wikipedia)

Comment: Similar, but not about race specifically: [Word meaning the reverse of 'xenophobia', to indicate an irrational fear or hatred of one's own countrymen](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/1974/191178)

Comment: Thanks - both of those are definitely related.

Comment: @Gio Please don't answer questions in the comments; post that as an answer instead.

Comment: @Laurel, why do you regard these two questions as only similar, rather than outright duplicates? Note that the OP is using *race* loosely.

Comment: @jsw29 Only if we assume the term "race" was intended to be used loosely. Perhaps the best option would be for OP to remove "or country" from this question (since an answer that only covers race wouldn't be appropriate on the other question) or specify why "oikophobia" from the other question doesn't work. Now, if *oikophobia* is the term they're looking for, the question here should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @Laurel, it's not just the OP's use of 'or country', but also the examples (*Russo-, Anglo-*), that indicate that the OP's focus is not on race, in the now-dominant sense of that word.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the word for someone who doesn't appreciate their culture/heritage?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/203365/2085) Or this? [What is a word that means someone who hates their own race?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/259003/2085)

Comment: @tchrist thank-you for the suggestions but no, they miss badly. The question asks for a prefix indicating pertaining to one's own-race or own-country whereas the suggested duplicates ask for substantially different things.

Comment: @it'sahirecarbaby What's wrong with stemming words like *patriot* and *nationalist* for your cultural alienation thing? Does self-hatred on a national or racial  or arbitrary type-group basis really need a new combining form that has never existed before and which nobody knows what means? Why can't you just spell it out in simple multiword English instead of plucking obscure Greek terms out of Homer nobody will have heard of? Plus what's wrong with reusing *autophobia*? Yes, it means something else but people will think it means fear of cars so it doesn't matter if you give it a new sense. :)

Comment: @tchrist I just think own-race or own-country either must have a prefix already, or should have because it's a regularly-needed concept. I'm thinking like e.g. autogynephilia which arose in the 1990s and is now an accepted word, because a niche existed for it in the light of increased gender ideology. Similar growth is now taking place in the discussion of economic migrancy as the developing world becomes better educated, more globally aware, and more mobile.

Answer (score 2):

### Patriaphobia

It was formed from *patria* (a somewhat obscure word of Latin origin that means "one's own country") and *phobia* (which we also get from Latin). Its main claim to fame is that it was used by Pope Francis:

> But he cautioned against "fantasies of patriaphobia," saying that he would visit Argentina when the opportunity presented itself and hinting that the trip could also include Uruguay and southern Brazil. —[CNA](https://www.catholicnewsagency.com/news/246765/pope-francis-confirms-plans-to-go-to-hungary-for-international-eucharistic-congress-in-september)

It's also been used in a couple of older sources, such as [The Pillar of Fire](https://books.google.com/books?id=A5dJAAAAIAAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&printsec=frontcover&pg=PA21&dq=%22patriaphobia%22&hl=en&source=gb_mobile_entity) (1915).

Comment: Nice, thanks. Patria must be same derivation as patriot.  Is there a reason for patriaphobia over patriophobia or even patriphobia?  As "patria" (as meaning of country) is derived from, and indicates of the father such as in patriarchy. I wonder is there a way to discriminate of own country specifically?

Comment: The term *patriphobia* is in use, but half the time is used to refer to a [fear/hatred of fathers](https://patriphobic.wordpress.com/).

Answer (score 0):

"One's own" has a prefix in latin of proprio-. This is evident in the words proprietor and proprioception, and in a modified form in property.

"Race" in latin comes as its own prefix: gen-, the word genus meaning race.

Try combining them like so: propriogenus.

Comment: This **could** be a word for the phenomenon in question, but **is** it? If somebody used that word, without explaining what its intended meaning is, do you think he would be understood?

Comment: @Lambie, the OP presumably wants a word to use in communication. For a word to be suitable for that purpose, it needs to be understood.

Comment: @jsw29 Yes, but that is not up to the inventor. It's up to the writer who uses it.

Comment: Inventions, strings not in the lexicon, are expressly off-topic on ELU.  I'd not call it a word. Productivity is not absolute in English.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, that objection should be made to the question, which explicitly asked ' . . . or can one create . . . '.

Comment: @jsw29 I'm addressing the 'who cares?' attitude.

Comment: A fabulous answer. So it would be propriogenophobia.   There should be special cases where invention should be on-topic here, something I will propose in meta.  If you propose propriogenophobia, I can accept your answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth the proposed prefix is within the lexicon, and the dicsussion of prefixes is on-topic therefore your objection fails.

Comment: @ it's a hire car baby Prefixation isn't totally productive. One can't use simplistic rules to create words at will. The answer here includes 'Try combining them like so: _propriogenus_', which would be rejected by teachers and editors, _is_ rejected by my spell-checker, and as a candidate not listed in any mainline dictionary is off-topic on ELU (check the regulations).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I like your critique, and I claim no authority on the proper formation of words. My suggestion of "propriogenus" that would lead to the solution of "propriogenophobia" would solve the writer's need to create a single word that conveys the desired meaning. However, it is rather cumbersome and should not be deemed a word until no other better option is discovered. I know very little Greek, so there might be some solution there that trumps mine.